# Is it possible to compute this limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

So, in one of practicing problems I got the following for $x >= 0$ :

$$|f(x) - 3| =< \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} $$

We are asked if $f(x)$ accept a limit at $+\infty$ , if so we need to find it .

**My Approach**

Using limit comparison, I thought that I can compute the limit of $\frac{1}{x² +1 }$ at $+\infty$ and use limit comparison rules to get the limit of $f(x)$ . So I'd get someting like that .

$$lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{1}{x² + 1} = 0^+$$

But from all the limit comparison law, there's no one which tell you the limit of $f(x)$ based on my kind of result . So my answer was that we can't know what's the limit of $f(x)$ at $+\infty$ .

However I'm still thinking that I'm wrong, am I ? If so, How can I find the limit of $f$ here ?

Answer (score 1):

$$|f(x) - 3| \le \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty}|f(x) - 3|\le\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^2 + 1}$$
Id est since $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^2 + 1}=0$ :
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}|f(x) - 3|\le0$$
But $|f(x) - 3|\geq0 \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty}|f(x) - 3|\geq0 $.
So $\lim_{x\to\infty}|f(x) - 3|=0$, so $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=3$.